# How to call a closure passed into a function?

Tags: closures, swift

I suspect I am missing something really obviously wrong here, so forgive me if I am being a bit thick.

All the examples I see for closures are for passing a closure to the array map function. I want to write my own function which takes a closure

This is what I am attempting

```
func closureExample(numberToMultiply : Int, myClosure : (multiply : Int) -> Int) -> Int
{
    // This gets a compiler error because it says myClosure is not an Int
    // I was expecting this to do was to invoke myClosure and return an Int which
    // would get multiplied by the numberToMultiply variable and then returned
    return numberToMultiply * myClosure
}
```

I am completely stumped on what I am doing wrong

Please help!!

Comment: try `return numberToMultiply * myClosure(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same way you call any function, with `()`.

```
return numberToMultiply * myClosure(multiply: anInteger)
```

A working example:

```
func closureExample(numberToMultiply : Int, myClosure : (multiply : Int) -> Int) -> Int {
    return numberToMultiply * myClosure(multiply: 2)
}

closureExample(10, { num in
    return 2*num
}) // 40
```

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer as it is syntactically correct i.e it has the variable name myClosure(multiply:2) rather than myClosure(2). I don't know what I was thinking with this, I was expecting the closure to be passed in to have encapsulated the variables passed into it when the function was called. It's obvious now that that was not the case

Comment: I added that when I ran it in the playground, just to be sure :)

Comment: I also wanted to thank everyone who responded. The members of this site are always really helpful. Any one else finding playground a bit buggy?

Answer (score 1):

You treat a closure parameter just like a function named with the parameter's name. `myClosure` is the closure that needs to operate on `numberToMultiply`, so you want:

```
return myClosure(numberToMultiply)
```

That will pass numberToMultiply to your closure, and return the return value.